# UIView in UIScrollview. frame.origin not changing on scrolling, can't detect collision

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a screen containing:

- UIView A
- UIScrollView, which contains UIView B

The UIScrollView overlaps with UIView A (up until about halfway through it), allowing me to "drag" UIView B and make it overlap it with UIView A. This is so that when I let go of it, UIView B bounces nicely back into its original position (I don't want to be able to drag it all around the screen, just from its starting point onto UIView A)

Now, I'm trying to detect a collision when the UIViews overlap. However, none is ever detected. I am using convertRect:toView: to get coordinates on the same system, but from tracing UIView B's coordinates in its touchesMoved I see that "dragging" (scrolling the UIScrollView, really) doesn't affect its frame's origin coordinates. They are the same in touchedBegan as they are every time touchedMoved fires.

I'm assuming this is because UIView B isn't really moving anywhere, UIScrollView is, meaning that the UIView's origin point is always the same, even if its absolute coordinates aren't. Any suggestion on how to handle this?

[image]

Comment: You should check the scroll view's content offset property, that's what will change when you scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be overlap when scrollView.frame.origin.x + viewB.frame.size.width + scrollView.contentOffset.x >= viewA.frame.origin.x

**After Edit:**

I couldn't get the scroll view to work so I tried it another way that worked pretty well. Instead of a scroll view, I just used a rectangular view with a background color, and added the blue square to it. I gave the blue square a set width and height in IB, centered it in the long skinny view (in the y direction), and had one other constraint to the left side of that long view. The IBOutlet leftCon is connected to that constraint. I then used this code to drag it, and have it go back when I let go:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panner;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leftCon;
@property (strong,nonatomic) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@end

@implementation ViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *blueSquare;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    [blueSquare addGestureRecognizer:self.panner];
}

- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint translate = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    if (self.leftCon.constant <160)
        if (self.leftCon.constant > 100) NSLog(@"Bang! We have a collision");
        self.leftCon.constant = translate.x;
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        [self startDisplayLink];
    }
}


-(void)startDisplayLink {
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(bounceBack:)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)stopDisplayLink {
    [self.displayLink invalidate];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}


-(void)bounceBack:(CADisplayLink *) link {
    self.leftCon.constant -= 12;
    if (self.leftCon.constant < 2) {
        [self stopDisplayLink];
        self.leftCon.constant = 2;
    }
}
```

The numbers in the translate code (160 and 100) were determined empirically by logging. The 160 number keeps it from going off the right edge of the long view, and the 100 number is where it starts to overlap the black box.

Comment: Tried this in UIView B's touchesBegan, but its superview's contentOffset is always {0, 0}

Also set the UIScrollView's delaysContentTouches to NO, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Jay, so when you scroll, the content offset doesn't change?

Comment: that's what it looks like. It's bizarre. touchesMoved gets called correctly as I scroll but the contentOffset in the log output never changes.

EDIT: this seems to be an issue with the UIScrollView's contentSize. I increased it and ran a test; the contentOffset is updating now. Will work a bit more with it and figure out what's wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm tracing the contentOffset on the UIView's touchesMoved. However, it seems that it doesn't get updated as I'm scrolling: if I scroll all the points reported are the same; if I let go and start scrolling again, all the new ones are the same but different to the previous ones. Not updating live as I'm scrolling

Comment: @Jay, when you move the blue view to the right, is that the normal scroll direction, or is that the direction that it bounces off of, like pulling down on a table view?

Comment: It actually bounces on either direction. I had the contentSize width set to the same width as the UIView and clipsToBounds set to NO so I could drag and have it automatically bounce back to the starting position on release; this way the UIScrollView is displayed on screen as in the image in my post, but since anything past the right border of the UIView isn't part of the contentSize, the contentOffset isn't being updated.

Comment: I guess I'll have to make the contentSize as wide as the UIScrollView's width, then detect a release and programmatically move the UIView to the starting position?

Comment: @Jay, if the content size is the same as the width, then it won't scroll at all. It might be better not to use a scroll view at all. Attach a pan gesture recognizer to the blu view, and move it back in code when you let go.